# Text separation in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to separate text in Excel. For example I have:
    1/2/3/4
and I want to get:
    4.
So regardless of the number of slashes, my desired outcome is all figures in front of first slash from the right.
I wrote RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)) but it returns 2/3/4 instead of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

For a true number,

```
=--TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use do this way too:

Mid(A1, Find("/", A1, LEN(A1)-1) + 1, LEN